# Javascript dropdown like Google Translate

Tags: javascript

Anybody knows if the Google Translate's dropdown is Open Source?
http://translate.google.com/

I've taked some searches but don't found it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not just proprietary, the code is also obfuscated. Google doesn't usually open-source their products. You might as well be asking if Gmail is open source.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the custom dropdown you want, try this one from filament:

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html

Explanation here:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/